# Ach processing adding special characters in file

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, choetl

> I have to generate ACH file(my code is below). whenever bank is processing this. it add some special characters in front of the file. Unable to figure out

What can be the proper way to generate the ACH file having NACHA format, so that it can be processed without any faliure

```
try
            {
                //Set this flag to fix the issue
                ChoETLFrxBootstrap.IsSandboxEnvironment = false;
                ChoNACHAConfiguration config = new ChoNACHAConfiguration();
                config.DestinationBankRoutingNumber = "xxxxxxxxxx";                
                config.OriginatingCompanyId = "xxxxxxxxxx";
                config.DestinationBankName = ("SOME Bank").ToUpper();
                config.OriginatingCompanyName = ("Organisation Name").ToUpper();
                config.ReferenceCode = ("mgmt").ToUpper();
                config.BlockingFactor = 10;
                var unitowners = Achbll.GetUnitOwnerPaymentList(Dt).ToList();
                var FileName = "ACH_" + ((DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyy hh:mm:ss")).Replace(" ", "_").Replace(":", "_")) + ".txt";
                var backpath = "~/CondoDocuments/DocumentLibrary/AchFiles/" + FileName;
                var path = Server.MapPath(backpath); //HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + backpath;

                using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                {
                    fs.Close();
                    fs.Dispose();
                }

                using (var nachaWriter = new ChoNACHAWriter(path, config))
                {
                    using (var bw2 = nachaWriter.CreateBatch(200, "PPD", "DIR DEBIT", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), null, null, '1', null, null))
                    {
                        foreach (var owner in unitowners)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(owner.AccountNo) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(owner.BankRoutingCode))
                            {

                                var UA = Cipher.decrypt(owner.AccountNo);
                                var BR = Cipher.decrypt(owner.BankRoutingCode);
                                var Name = owner.UnitOwnerName.Split(' ');
                                if (Name.Length > 1)
                                {
                                    using (var entry = bw2.CreateDebitEntryDetail(27, BR.ToString(), UA.ToString(), 5, " 18H00A " + owner.UnitNo.ToString(), (Name[1] + ", " + Name[0]).ToUpper().ToString()))
                                    {
                                        //entry.CheckDigit = '0';
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    using (var entry = bw2.CreateDebitEntryDetail(
                                                                                    27,
                                                                                    BR.ToString(),
                                                                                    UA.ToString(),
                                                                                    new decimal(5.25),
                                                                                    " 18H00B " + owner.UnitNo.ToString(),
                                                                                    (Name[0]).ToUpper().ToString()))

                                    {
                                        //entry.CheckDigit = '0';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                AchFiles obj = new AchFiles
                {
                    FileName = FileName,
                    Path = "../CondoDocuments/DocumentLibrary/AchFiles/" + FileName
                };

                Achbll.AddAchFiles(obj);

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

> I am attaching the screen shot of the processed data
>   [image]

Comment: You are using the wrong encoding for the file write operation.

Comment: what do you mean, please elaborate

Comment: Your writer component uses the wrong character encoding. If you set this correctly, you will receive the desired result.

Comment: can you please give me solution or write the code line for this ?

Comment: what i am generating is a text file. what should be the appropriate encoding for this ?

Comment: Something like `config.Encoding = xxxx`

Comment: It seems there is no encodign in [ChoNACHAConfiguration](https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL.NACHA/blob/master/ChoETL.NACHA/Configuration/ChoNACHAConfiguration.cs)

Comment: However, an encoding is explicitly used in '[ChoNACHAWriter.cs](https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL.NACHA/blob/54e34852bb3b4ddb366a8268aa922008831f0249/ChoETL.NACHA/ChoNACHAWriter.cs#L33)'.

Comment: Also, the Encoding property is inherited from [ChoFileRecordConfiguration](https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL/blob/ca35dc968787588e4bccbd385294f45a8e8df538/src/ChoETL/File/ChoFileRecordConfiguration.cs#L186-L191). The default value would be Encoding.UTF8 if no other encoding is specified.